# How to export all the comments added as part of a merge request on git - ibm bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, gitlab, gitlab-api

How can i export or get all the comments added as part of merge request on git - IBM Bluemix.
I got options from [gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html#namespaced-path-encoding).

Any API is available from ibm bluemix git ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think this is the API you are looking for:

https://git.ng.bluemix.net/help/api/notes.md#list-all-merge-request-notes (ng might be different depending on your region)

Here's an example request:

```
https://git.ng.bluemix.net/api/v4/projects/:id/merge_requests/:merge_request_iid/notes?private_token=YOUR_PRIVATE_TOKEN
```

Comment: I see this has a vote down, but I don't understand why this is the case. Is there anything else you need for this answer, or can I improve upon it?

Comment: Let me know if that works for you or if you need any more assistance.

Comment: /v4/:id/ , how can get ID ? is it the repo name? @joe

Comment: When you hit the /projects endpoint, it gives you a list of all the projects and the ids.

Comment: Then if you hit the /api/v4/projects/:id/merge_requests it gives you a list of merge requests and their ids and iids iirc

Comment: You need the private token query parameter on both of those requests (also, when I say /projects, I mean /api/v4/projects)

Comment: i got it , but just commit messages am getting not comments.

Answer (score 0):

The version of Git used by the IBM Cloud is based on [GitLab Community Edition](https://about.gitlab.com/).  You should be able to use the [GitLab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html), to do anything you want to automate.